# How to rehydrate Identity property in Model when a new user logs in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have a model, for example,

```
public class OccupationType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userId")]
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

That sets a many-to-1 relationship to an `ApplicationUser` object, which is where I house user identities.

My controllers typically take a model like the above and persist the incoming data, like for example:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(string id, OccupationType occupationtype)
{        
    // DO BUSINESS LOGIC

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

While a typical payload from the client is more like this:

```
{
   UserId = "###-###-..."
   Type = "..."
}
```

No `ApplicationUser` property. However, when this object is instatiated, an `ApplicationUser` object is included in the model. The first time a user uses the controller, the identity of the `ApplicationUser` is that of the user bearing the token that was authorized to use the controller action.

This is fine until I send another request with a different user. Then, even though a new token is used by a different user, `ApplicationUser` remains the same as the first user.

I'm perplexed. How is the a user chosen to automatically populate the `ApplicationUser` property? And why isn't it aware of a new principal when a new token is used to make a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC ModelBinder probably binds the posted `UserId` to the `occupationType.UserId`. After that the `occupationType.ApplicationUser` is fetched based on that UserId. The bearer token has nothing to do with this.

So my bet is that the client sends the same UserId in the second request.